# No such kernel named pythonjvsc when converting a jupyter notebook to html

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have a very simple jupyter notebook in Visual Studio Code:

```
print("hello")
```

and I want to create an HTML from it.

I am using this command in the python terminal:

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html  --no-input --no-prompt .\test1.ipynb
```

but I am getting this error:

```
jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named pythonjvsc74a57bd0f240191ec4420135543f68463e6c8f002b19e83e792c8df3dc5d9bba67575c13
```

it was working some days ago, so maybe a side effect of updating Visual Studio Code.

Google search showed me similar questions but all related to Conda but I am not using conda. it is python 3.8.7

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: On what operating system do you work, and how did you install Python? How did you install jupyter / nbconvert? Did you try re-installing jupyter?

Comment: @S.A. I am on windows. I am using visual studio code and yes I uninstall and install all software.

Comment: Thanks, please tell us how you installed python, and jupyter.